# Deploy Blazor to Firebase and have error Firebase Hosting Setup Complete

Tags: firebase, blazor

I want to deploy my Blazor project with Firebase hosting. I have tried a few times to deploy but have the same erorr `Firebase Hosting Setup Complete`. [Deploy Blazor project](https://blazor-84ff9.web.app/)

```
firebase login
firebase init
What do you want to use as your public directory? public
Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? No
Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
File public/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
Skipping write of public/index.html
firebase deploy
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can deploy to firebase hosting only client side app. So your app must be Blazor WebAssembly single-page app. Moreover you are not overwriting `index.html` so you will see the default firebase file (you can check [this](https://blazor-84ff9.web.app/index.html)). So you have to overwrite default `index.html` with yours.

Comment: This project is a empty project for testing, do I need to change anything in the project? I did try both in `Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes`

Comment: Be sure your project is a client side app. After you have to "compile" your project for release and deploy the release version of your project. You can find a step by step procedure at this link https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-deploy-blazor-webassembly-to-firebase-hosting